# My Domain Name dosn't point to my amazon S3 static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

So I am hosting my website on AWS S3 and even though my domain is with Route 53 and I have setup the hosted zones as I have seen in the AWS tutorials. But even though I have done this, it does not seem to work and this has greatly confused me. I'm not going to post any of the information about the name servers and other things, just in case something could happen to the domain, but I was wondering if anyone could help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I force refreshed my DNS cache on my computer, and now when I go to my domain, it comes up with the error "dial tcp: lookup verticeinteractive.co.uk on 8.8.4.4:53: server misbehaving" what does that mean?

Comment: I then did a DNS ping tool, and it is saying it cannot find any name servers, even though there are 4 name servers defined

Comment: is verticeinteractive.co.uk your domain? If so the domain servers do not point at AWS. Otherwise it's hard to guess without information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways on top of my mind. One is to set up on your domain records a type A sub domain pointing to your instance ip. The bad thing is that if your restart your instance you will get another public IP.

The second option is going for configure Amazon route 53. There are plenty tutorials available and there is a cost for using this other service

Comment: I havee it configured in Amazon route 53, but the domain says it doesn't point to an ip address when I trouble shoot it. Should I add a picture of the aliases (blurring out the name servers)

Comment: What type of record are you trying to add on your domain A? Have you tried with a name record?

Comment: Should I add it as a CNAME? I have it as an Alias, so A

Comment: Both should work if properly setup. Having a cname record will be a better approach, because if you access you instance from inside the virtual network it will resolve the private address of the instance. You can check what I'm talking about in this forum post:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=319837

Comment: This may just be me, but I don't really understand that. What would I have to input into the CNAME since my cloudfront link does not work in the CNAME alias box. The message that comes back with "No AWS resource exists with the Alias Target that you specified."